# device with android lollipop crash after update to fcm

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-5.0-lollipop

recently I have updated from GCM to FCM in my android project, and after that the app start to crash on android note3 with lollipop OS

this is what found on the log

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash not found.

I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.crash:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.crash:215
```

does anyone face a problem like this and be able to solve it ?

**EDIT**

I am using firebase version 12.0.1

**EDIT2**

```
ext.support_version = '27.1.1'
ext.google_servcie_version = '12.0.1'
ext.firebase_version = '12.0.1'
```